# Which Axiom does this definition fail?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, axioms

> Consider the set of vectors $\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}\vec{u}=(x,y,z)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with standard addition, but scalar multiplication defined by $r\vec{u}=(r^2x,r^2y,r^2z)$. This is not a vector space. Determine which vector space axiom fails and exhibit a counterexample to demonstrate the failure of that axiom.

I have attempted this and have come to believe it is the $r(s\vec{v}) = (rs)\vec{v}$ axiom that it fails.

I am new to this subject and am hoping for some guidance/confirmation.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqwTO.png

Comment: It would have been much better to use MathJax to quote the problem in your post rather than as an image (I think you also may need some reputation points to post images). ....

Comment: ... the axiom you cite does not fail. Your list of axioms should include one about  $(r + s) \mathbf{v}$. Have a look at that axiom and consider some specific examples for $r$ and $s$.

Comment: @fleablood: I agree about the ordering of the vector space axioms. But in the OP's defence, he stated what the axiom was and included a link in his comment to an image of the problem he's trying to solve.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that when I reread her post.  That axiom works as if $u = (x,y,z)$ the $r(su) = r(s^2x, s^2y,s^2z)=(r^2s^2x, r^2s^2y, r^2s^2z)$ and $(rs)u = ((rs)^2x, (rs)^2y, (rs)^z)$ so that is good.

Comment: Oops! Apologies to Kerry if I was wrong in reading Kerry as a male name.

Comment: oh so r(sv) = (rs)v doesn't fail?

And thanks Rob I'll look into (r+s)v.

I wish I was able to post a photo of my attempts...

Comment: Have a look at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference too.

Comment: (r + s)v = $(r^2x,r^2y,r^2z) + (s^2x,s^2y,s^2z)$ right? and isnt that equal to rv + sv? it looks like a vector space to me and that why im so lost...

Comment: @KerryFishcer No, $(r+s)v = ((r+s)^2 x, (r+s)^2 y, (r+s)^2 v)$.

Comment: ooooooooohhhhhhhh THANK YOU ALL SO MUCH!

Now I feel stupid hah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial question has been answered already, so let me explain how to think about this problem—at least, how I thought about the problem.

You can see that $r\pmb{v}$ is never going to be a negative multiple of $\pmb{v}$, but we know that for vector spaces, $(-1) \cdot \pmb{v} = - \pmb{v}$. So now you need to either look up or try your best to remember the proof that $(-1) \cdot \pmb{v} = - \pmb{v}$ to see what the key axioms that are used in that proof.

Because you have the standard addition on $\mathbf{R}^3$, all the axioms that refer just to the vector addition and not the scalar multiplication will always be satisfied. So what you are left with is:

1. $r(s\pmb{v}) = (rs)\pmb v$
2. $(r + s)\pmb v = r \pmb v + s \pmb v$
3. $r(\pmb v + \pmb w) = r\pmb v + r \pmb w$
4. $1 \pmb v = \pmb v$

The essential property of the number $(-1)$ is the equation $1 + (-1) = 0$ which involves both $1$ and $+$ (scalar addition). Of the 4 axioms, the fourth mentions $1$ and you can check that easily, and the second uses the scalar addition. So because the essential equation $1 + (-1) = 0$ uses scalar addition, that tells us to look at the second axiom.

Answer (score 1):

(r+s)**u** = ${(r+s)^2x,(r+s)^2y,(r+s)^2z)}$ = {$(r^2+2rs+s^2)x,(r^2+2rs+s^2)y,(r^2+2rs+s^2)z$} $\ne$ r**u**+s**u** = $(r^2x,r^2y,r^2z)+(s^2x,s^2y,s^2z)$

Therefor,
(r+s)**u** $\ne$ r**u**+s**u**

Comment: this look right?

Comment: It's correct except, for completeness, you should give values for $r$ and $s$ that demonstrate that $(r + s)^2 \ne r^2 + s^2$. Here it matters that the field is $\mathbf{R}$, if you were working in a field where $2  = 0$, then this proof doesn't work (and actually, I think, it will form a vector space).

Comment: @TrevorGunn: yes, in a field $k$ of characteristic 2, $x \mapsto x^2$ is a field automorphism and if you permute the usual view of $k^n$ as a vector space via this automorphism you will still get a vector space.